# Play/Ebean not fetching all attributes of ManyToOne related object

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I have a Play 2.2 application, and I'm using ebean 3.2.2.
I have two tables: UserModel and Schedule.  A UserModel can have one Schedule, and a Schedule can have many UserModels.
Here is what the classes look like:

```
@Entity
public class UserModel extends Model {
    @Id
    public String email;
    public String other, attributes;

    @ManyToOne
    public Schedule defaultSchedule;

    @OneToMany
    public List<Task> tasks;
}

@Entity
public class Schedule extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @OneToMany
    public List<UserModel> owners;

    public String other, attributes;
}
```

I'll do an update to the UserModel like so:

```
userModel.defaultSchedule = newSchedule;
userModel.update();
```

And when I run a query:

```
UserModel.find.where().eq("email", email).findUnique()
```

I look inside UserModel.defaultSchedule and find that only the Id is populated.  **The rest of the fields are all null, and this is the problem I'm trying to solve.**

The reason this is particularly baffling to me, is that I have another class:

```
@Entity
public class Task extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long taskId;
    public Boolean completed;

    @ManyToOne
    public UserModel assignedTo;

}
```

When I do a query for this type of object like so:

```
Task.find.where().eq("assignedTo.email", email).eq("completed", false).findList();
```

I'm finding that *all* of the fields of Task.assignedTo are populated (not just the Id).
**Why are the fields populated in this case, but not the first case?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is in how I was doing the query.  I was able to retrieve all of the attributes of the related object by adding a fetch to the query:

```
UserModel.find.fetch("defaultSchedule").where().eq("email", email).findUnique();
```